What is the fundamental solution for the backward heat equation?
According to the theorem of Malgrange and Ehrenpreis a fundamental solution exists for any PDE with constant coefficients. But I didn't manage to find in the literature an explicit formula  for the  backward heat equation $u_t+\Delta u=0$. So what is the formula or does the fundamental solution exist only as a (singular) distribution?

This would be the time reversal of the fundamental solution for the forward heat equation, i.e. $1_{t<0} \frac{1}{(4\pi |t|)^{n/2}} e^{-|x-y|^2/4|t|}$.  There's nothing particularly ill-posed (other than non-uniqueness) about the backwards heat equation when viewed as a spacetime equation with no initial condition; it's only the initial value problem (which is not covered by Malgrange-Ehrenpreis) which is so badly behaved.
